# Revisit SSIS: Error from ODBC provider when inserting into Always Encrypted table using CMK in Azure Key Store

Tags: ssis

I am having the same issue as [SSIS: Error from ODBC provider when inserting into Always Encrypted table using CMK in Azure Key Store](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240396/ssis-error-from-odbc-provider-when-inserting-into-always-encrypted-table-using) even with SSIS built in VS 2019 with the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. I am using .netProviders/odbc data driver and getting the following error:

[image: ADO.net/ ODBC]

```
Error: 0xC020844B at Data Flow Task, ADO NET Destination 
[2]: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: 
ERROR [CE269] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Error 12038 sending request to https://[****].vault.azure.net:443 

ERROR [CE263] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
****Error verifying signature of ECEK.**** 

ERROR [CE202] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
The keystore provider AZURE_KEY_VAULT failed to decrypt the ECEK https://[****].vault.azure.net:443/keys/CMKAuto2/[****...] with RSA_OAEP.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. My DB is Azure SQL DB. I can view the decrypted data from SSMS and can insert a row as well. But my SSIS data flow is not working.

Can anybody please help me out?